# ¿Cómo puedo pasar un for a un array.map?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando pasar un `for` que realicé para iterar los usuarios de un Array. Sería algo así:

```
for (let v=0; v < usuarios.length; v++){
 usuarios[v].esPremium = true;
}
return usuarios;
```

Y me gustaría hacer lo mismo pero con un `map` el cual tengo de momento de esta manera:

```
const uservip = usuarios.map(x => x.esPremium = true)
return resultado;
```

Comment: ya intentaste con un `.forEach(usuario=>console.log(usuario))`?

Comment: la verdad no he intentado con ese método, no lo conozco a profundidad, pero creo que es parecido al for que indique al inicio, el mismo funciona sin problema, pero solo quiero pasar ese metodo for a otro metodo, sea filter o forEach o reduce.. pero gracias de todas formas amigo sus respuestas son muy agradecidas.

Comment: Lo que quieres es asignar `true` a la propiedad `esPremium` a todos los usuarios del array?

Comment: Simple `const uservip = usuarios.map(x => {return {...x, esPremium : true}})`

Comment: O sin el return: `const uservip = usuarios.map(x => ({ ...x, esPremium: true }))`

Comment: José... Cúal es tu objetivo? Por qué quieres utilizar `map()`? Sabes para qué es? Sabes cuál es la diferencia entre `map()` y `forEach()`? Sabes cuál devuelve un arreglo nuevo y cuál modifica el arreglo existente? Si acaso existe una respuesta a esta pregunta, sería *Tienes que **investigar***

Comment: @Arriel mi objetivo es utilizar el metodo map, para crear un nuevo array, en donde el array de objeto "usuarios" que tiene la propiedad "esPremium" y su valor es "false", entonces debo cambiar ese valor a "true" probé haciendo un "for" y me fue bien, pero investigando leí acerca de "map" y dije probemos, no me fue tan bien. Hice mis investigaciones acerca de ambos forEach y map y si entiendo lo que hacen, pero no me gusta quedarme con la duda cuando agoto los metodos de investigación.. y recurrí a pedir ayuda aquí. Quieres más detalles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La idea que propone Jaime Menéndez diría que es bastante acertada. Como alternativa, también existe esta forma de hacerlo:

```javascript
const uservip = usuarios.map(usuario => {
  usuario.esPremium = true
  return usuario;
})
```

Esta alternativa es menos bonita que la de Jaime, pero quizás resulta más fácil de entender. La función que indicas dentro de `map` tiene que devolver el objeto modificado. Es decir, si como parámetro de la función tienes `usuario` o `x`, tienes que devolver ese mismo valor pero con la modificación que pretendes. Si quieres asignar a `true` el valor de la propiedad `esPremium`, primero debes modificar el valor de ese objeto y luego retornar el mismo. Tal y como expuse en el ejemplo y como ilustra Jaime en su comentario.

Espero esto te sirva. Saludos!

Comment: muy agradecido amigo, por haberte tomado el tiempo y poder responderme y explicarme detalladamente la función ".map" especificamente en lo que requiero.. de verdad me quedo muy claro todo.